# Calculation on complete filling

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать на js пересчет значений только после полного ввода числа (например 0.6789), так, чтоб пересчет не производился на значения 0 / 0.6 / 0.67 / 0.678 а считал только с финальным значением 0.6789. Или реализовать пересчет после переключения на другое поле input / text box / span, или после нажатия клавиши enter.
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Возможно всё... `if ( input.value.length < 6 ) return;`  Нужен ваш код, чтобы точнее ответить.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас к сожалению кода с собой нет. Сразу скину по возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю Ваш вопрос, а задан он к сожалению очень расплывчато. Вы спрашиваете как получать значение поля ввода, только когда данные введены.

Это реализуется прослушиванием события "change". Вот пример:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("input", function () {
    /* Эта функция будет вызываться при каждом изменении поля. */
  console.log("input: ", this.value);
});

input.addEventListener("change", function () {
    /* Эта функция будет вызываться только при потере фокуса, если поле было изменено */
  console.log("change: ", this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вот в чем дело, а я просто два события навесил oninput и onchange.